# Why does this array.prototype.find does not work?

Tags: javascript

I have the following object

```
const someobj = {constantValues: {status: [{value: 1, key : "enabled"},{value: 0, key: "disabled"},{value: 3, key: "archived"}]}}
```

And the following key

```
const keyFilter = "status"
```

I try to filter the object with the value 3 from someobj, so i do

```
const constantValueIsNumber = typeof someobj.constantValues.status[0].value === "number" ? true: false
const val = someobj.constantValues[keyFilter].find(i => i.value === constantValueIsNumber? Number("3"): "3")

console.log(val) // {value: 1, key: "enabled"}
```

WHy is it returning 1, when im filtering 3 and it should return

```
{value: 3, key: "archived"}
```

Comment: Both `3` and `"3"` are truthy. `.find()` first the first item the predicate tells it. I don't know what you expect by returning a three.

Comment: @VLAZ filter the object that has a value 3

Comment: Yes, and a predicate returns a true or false. Yours returns three. I have no idea how is JS expected to interpret that a number (or number as string) to means "you have to check the `value` property for this value".

Comment: @VLAZ how am I supposed to get the elements with value: 3 then

Comment: `.find(i => i.value === 3)` - Note: `find` will only return the first element for which the callback returns true. You probably need to use the `filter` method.

Comment: Right now you're jumping through hoops to figure out which type it even is. And in the process return a three instead of comparing to three.  Instead of doing all that, you could have used `Number(i.value)` to normalises to only a number. Or to make sure it's a string. It matters little, since in either case you no longer need three separate conditionals to try and find what to compare.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```js
const someobj = {constantValues: {status: [{value: 1, key : "enabled"},{value: 0, key: "disabled"},{value: 3, key: "archived"}]}};

const keyFilter = "status";
const valueToCheck = "3";

const val = someobj.constantValues[keyFilter].find(i => i.value.toString() === valueToCheck.toString());

console.log(val);
```

We convert all values to string so both numbers and strings work.

Comment: But I need to evaluate isnumber , because there are some objects where value is a string, and other its a number. So I cant remove that

Comment: You can use `==` instead of `===` to ensure `3 == "3"` evaluates to true.

Comment: If you need a number, simply change i.value to +i.value to convert it to number in any case.

Comment: Point is , I dont know if the objects value will be a string or a number, thats why i have to evaluate it. I cant convert it always to number

Comment: If it's a string, with the code I gave you, it gets converted to number. If it's a number, it just works without any conversion. +"3" === 3 works the same with 3 === 3 and +3 === 3.

Comment: Because sometimes its a string ,    "value" == "value"  ,  it isnt always a number

Comment: @mouchin777 I edited the code. I took an opposite approach to convert both to string. Now strings and numbers should all work.

Comment: So why not convert everything to a string?

Comment: @epascarello haha the timing :)

Answer (score 0):

your predicate was not written correctly; you should place parenthesis to define the order of operations. The `.find()` method has to be something like this

`const val = someobj.constantValues[keyFilter].find(i => i.value === (constantValueIsNumber? 3 : "3"))`

it outputs:
`val: {value: 3, key: 'archived'}`